# bootstrap table-responsive in a dynamic table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've A very large table that I display to the user with offset 20 .
My Problem is a smartphone when the user scroll down i load more rows to the table and the user can't see the scroll off bootstrap until he load all the table.

any help how to fix this problem ?!

Comment: Could you please share some examples about your implementation. It's easy to imagine your problem but hard to find the reason without having any code.

Comment: I've table rapped in div with class table-responsive , every time user reached end of the window i load more rows so each time the scroll falls down . so the user won't see it or be able to catch it . there's no much to share .

Comment: do you know another solution to handle table responsive ?! thanks.